# adding footer to one of the ListFragments' listview automatically adds footer to another one

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

So my app consists of two `ListFragment`s. Lets call them `ContentsList` and `TextList`. The problem is when I am adding a footer to the ListView of `ContentsList` like this (in the `onActivityCreated()` method:

```
lv = getListView();
v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_new,
                null);
lv.addFooterView(v);
```

It would automatically add a footer to a listview of the `TextList` ListView as well. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Can we please see your getListView() method? I assume they are on the same Activity?

Comment: Look, this getListView() is a standard method of a ListFragment. And each of my fragments extends this ListFragment. That is the answer for the first part of the question.

Comment: Even though it is indeed the same activity - it is different fragments and different ListViews. That is for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhu solved.

The problem was that one of my fragments was actually called "ListFragment" and at some point my fragment and the actual class ListFragment were confused and it caused a problem.

I took this idea from [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html) but it seems that that guy has already tweaked it for the better. Anyway I shall punch him in the face on the first occasion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this . The problem I think is you have two layouts with `@android:id/list` in a single activity used by different fragments. What you could do is differentiate the Layouts that hold the listview with different ids.

And then

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewbyId(R.id.contentslayout);

Yourlistview = (ListVIew)layout.findviewbyid(R.id.list)
```

If this does not work, then may be you will have to set different tag to each listview and use findViewbytag

Comment: Such a weird thing. Those two fragments are using the same ListView but they display different content and are inflated from different adapters. Confusing stuff